# Recursion issue when fetching external pages with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yahoo-api

I have a Google Chrome extension for exporting entries from a website. I can't get all entries by one query and I'm using a parameter for paging, i.e. `'...&p=' + pageNumber++`. I do this with connecting to my web server and this is not a problem with PHP. But I found that I can generate pdf files directly using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and I decided to get rid of the server side help.

Now I want to fetch the entries with jQuery Ajax. The problem is that I don't know in advance how many pages I have to fetch.

My current solution is:

```
function runRecursionTest(url, pageNumber){
    var currentUrl = url + '?p=' + pageNumber;
    
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
        "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
        encodeURIComponent(currentUrl)+
        "%22&format=json'&callback=?"
    ).done(function(data) {
        if(data.results[0]){
            data = filterData(data.results[0]);

            $('#export-target-list').append($(data).find('#entry-list').html());

            runRecursionTest(url, pageNumber++);
        } else {
            alert('Stop! Last page: '+(pageNumber-1));
        }
    });
}
```

It seems logical, huh? But suprisingly it fails. Too much requests are sent even when I have 1 page only. Can't stop it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're using $.getJSON to get XML ?

Comment: Didn't think that this is the problem. I can fetch the results correctly anyway.